# Function not working when inside a jQuery Block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What I want to do:
I want to get data from a server using AJAX.

My problem:
When I call the search-function from inside a jQuery Block (e.g. $(document).ready), I get a "TypeError: $.ajax is not a function" Error, but when I call the function from the script block it works and I receive the data.

What I tried/Other info:

- It doesn't matter if the function declarations are inside or outside the jQuery block
- It doesn't matter if it's the ready or any other jQuery function
- I pasted the code right into the jQuery function, it doesn't work either
- It doesn't matter where I place the functions (above, below, head, body, etc.)
- I'm using the full version of jQuery, so it's not because of the slim version
- I'm also using Bootstrap 4
- I'm working on it locally

My code:

```js
function search()
  {
    Object.keys(SystemEnum).forEach(function(key) {
      searchRequest(search_url, key, "Test").then(data => {
        console.log("data successfully loaded.");
        }).catch(function(err) {
          console.error("Error:" + err);
      });
    });
  }

function searchRequest(URL, platform, name) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: URL,
      type: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
        resolve(data);
      },
      error: function(e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    });
  });
}
        

$(document).ready( function() {   
  $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function () {
    if($(this).val().length > 2)
    {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      
      //This doesn't work
      search();
    }
    else if($(this).val().length <= 2)
    {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

      $("#searchTable tr").filter(function() {
        $(this).show()
      });
    }
  });
          
});                     
        
//This works        
search();
```

I'm not really seeing the issue and I couldn't find anything similiar on the web, hopefully one of you can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: What do you get with `console.log($.fn.jquery)`?  Is it what you're expecting? (add directly in front of search() in both places)

Comment: Is jQuery included in the source ? I just ran your code in stackoverflow's with jQuery included, I didn't get the "TypeError: $.ajax is not a function". Tough I was getting another error which was undefined error for `SystemEnum `.

Comment: @rprakash Yes (<script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>), also tried it with the 3.3.1 version, but also no success.

Comment: @freedomn-m For the search-call outside of the function it prints just the version number, for the one inside it prints: 3.3.1 -ajax,-ajax/jsonp,-ajax/load,-ajax/parseXML,-ajax/script,-ajax/var/location,-ajax/var/nonce,-ajax/var/rquery,-ajax/xhr,-manipulation/_evalUrl,-event/ajax,-effects,-effects/Tween,-effects/animatedSelector

Comment: @Tentix can you try adding this `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
` instead.

Comment: @rprakash Same error.

Comment: If it's different, then you may have 2 different jquery versions being loaded.  Check the *rendered* output closely.  If you're using any sort of framework (MVC/Wordpress) they tend to add *another* jquery at the bottom of the HTML which will overwrite the one you added at the top.

Comment: `-ajax` indicates the (2nd) loaded jquery is a slim version, so no ajax.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you, there actually was another version at the bottom and it fixed it! Really appreciated.